# Android verify signature always returns false

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, signature, spongycastle

I'm trying to verify some signed content using ECDSA and spongycastle. Here is the code I'm using to generate the keypair with the brainpoolP512t1 ec curve:

> ```
> public static KeyPair getKeyPairbrainpoolP512t1() throws Exception {
>     KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SC");
>     ECNamedCurveParameterSpec curveParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolP512t1");
>     keyPairGenerator.initialize(curveParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
>     return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
> }
> ```

Here is the code I'm using to sign and verify signatures:

```
private byte[] ecdsaSign(ECPrivateKey key, byte[] content) throws Exception {
    Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "SC");
    ecdsaSign.initSign(key);
    ecdsaSign.update(content);
    byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();

    return signature;
}

public static boolean ecdsaVerify(ECPublicKey key, byte[] content, byte[] signature) throws Exception {
    Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "SC");
    ecdsaVerify.initVerify(key);
    ecdsaVerify.update(content);
    boolean result = ecdsaVerify.verify(signature);
    return result;
}
```

I'm passing in the bytes of a simple string message that was signed using the private key, and also the public key in order to verify. I'm always getting false however. What am I doing wrong? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong. I was exporting the keys to PEM in order to have them in string format prior to calling sign and verify, and then decoding back to private key original format. When I omitted this conversion and called Verify directly with the private key (without the PEM string back and forth conversion), the content got verified.